# Build list in Python

Tags: python

I have a list ['15663627', '5904116', '7162142', '9854216', '55024914'] in return I want to get ['15663627', '5904116'], ['15663627','7162142'] etc. so it should be first element with every next...

Comment: If only we can understand your question...

Comment: I have a list ['15663627', '5904116', '7162142', '9854216', '55024914'] in return I want to get ['15663627', '5904116'], ['15663627','7162142'] etc. so it should be first element with every next...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Im getting from your examples is you're looking for something like this?..

```
def custom_sequence_1(input_list):
    output=[]
    for i in range(len(input_list)-1):
        output.append(list(set([input_list[i+1],input_list[0]])))
return(output)

print(custom_sequence_1(['15663627', '5904116', '7162142', '9854216', '55024914']))

#outputs: [['15663627', '5904116'], ['15663627', '7162142'], ['15663627', '9854216'], ['15663627', '55024914']]


# or for a little more specific to your wording:
def custom_sequence_2(input_list):
    output=[]
    first=input_list[0]
    for i in input_list:
        output.append([first,i])
    output.pop(0)
    return(output)

print(custom_sequence_2(['15663627', '5904116', '7162142', '9854216', '55024914']))

# outputs: [['15663627', '5904116'], ['15663627', '7162142'], ['15663627', '9854216'], ['15663627', '55024914']]
```

Comment: I have a list ['15663627', '5904116', '7162142', '9854216', '55024914'] in return I want to get ['15663627', '5904116'], ['15663627','7162142'] etc. so it should be first element with every next...

Comment: Technically I had it, order wasn't exactly specified in the question.

Comment: and why there is output.pop(0)

Comment: The output.pup(0) removes the first item from the list that would read "['15663627','15663627']"

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine the first element of your list with every following element of the list. This can be done by using a list comprehension.

```
data = ['15663627', '5904116', '7162142', '9854216', '55024914']
result = [[data[0], value] for value in data[1:]]
```

result is now `[['15663627', '5904116'], ['15663627', '7162142'], ['15663627', '9854216'], ['15663627', '55024914']]`.

---

If you're not familiar with list comprehensions then read about it in the tutorial. The following loop does the same.

```
result = []
for value in data[1:]:
    result.append([data[0], value])
```

Comment: and how should I redo it for more then one list in the file? it shold look like: with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for i in f:
        i = i.split()
        for value in i[1:]:
            res.append([i[0], value])

Comment: Hard to say because of the missing indentation, but it looks good. You might need to use `i.strip().split()` instead of `i.split()` to get rid of a trailing newline character.